# Wine issues with Runescape

Tags: firefox, wine, java, executable

Believe it or not, I play Runescape. I find the game to be interesting.

Out of my curiosity, I found that there is a way to play the game in an executable file. However, there was no Linux download for this type of file, so I installed it with Wine, and it seemed to work fine.

The game loads up perfectly fine, until it finds updates. When it finds updates, it stops at exactly 92% every time I try running it and I must force quit the application. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: @BlueXRider: Are you sure? "Running third-party applications on Ubuntu" is listed in the "We welcome questions about:" listing on the page you linked to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following [this](http://www.sythe.org/showthread.php?t=456207) (yes, its got some age to it; but the game hasn't changed much since then) tutorial:

> Installing Java On Ubuntu for RuneScape By Renegades009
>
> **Step 1:** After a freshly installed Ubuntu system open up Synaptic
>   Package Manager.
>
> Enter the password you created at install. Now once its open go to
>   Settings Then click Repositories and make sure all boxes are checked
>   in first tab.
>
> [image]
>
> Now go back to the main window and search java. Scroll down to S and
>   mark installation for sun-java6-jre and sun-java6-plugin or something
>   like that.
>
> Don't forget to mark jre but I have that installed already. Once done
>   click apply and click ok to get dependencies. When done with install
>   restart browser and walla! RuneScape time!
>
> Also if RuneScape still doesn't seem to work for you reopen synaptic
>   and install openjdk.
>
> Please don't rip my guide or pictures without giving credit and link
>   back. Thanks enjoy!

Runescape is of the same caliber as Minecraft; which both use Java JRE as a game engine. Ubuntu comes with a default install of Java, but you often need to fine-tune the settings in Wine or download 3rd party repositories, to get them to work.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.