# Trying to play Runescape on Chromebook

Tags: java, google-chrome, chromium

Please be as simple and patient with me as possible. Not only is this my first experience with programming in any way, I'm surprised I got this far at all. I'm being serious. If you don't think it's necessary to explain, it's necessary to explain.

So I'm primarily using [this thread here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247518) to try to play runescape on my chromebook. I'm making this post while running Ubuntu (downloaded via the links in that thread), using Chromium web browser. I have a few concerns and have hit a wall.

1. I am not running chrome. I am running chromium. I was told in another thread that chrome is unnecessary to achieve what I'm going for, and is too much work to install compared to chromium (which will accomplish the same goal). Is this true?
2. I can't get to step three: Java. I have open JDK installed form [this source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get), and I have Icedtea installed from [this step](http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/2ig0gp/getting_the_icedtea_java_plug_in_on_my_chrome_in/). Runescape still isn't running, saying I don't have the latest version of Java.

I have gone [here](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Linux_Native_Clients#The_RuneScape_UNIX_Client_.28RSU_Client.29) as directed. I cannot extract and install the client (Squeeze can't open?), and when HikariKnight's post, I cannot extract the file he has linked (again, Squeeze can't open?).

I don't know what I'm doing. We can ignore everything I've done previously if we want to start from the knowledge that I'm running Chromium in Ubuntu. I don't care if I play it on a client or in browser.

Thank you for any and all help. And I'm sorry I'm so lost in all of this. (You have to start somewhere right?...)

Comment: For the question on chrome: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant (If anything I think chromium works better as the package has been done by the Ubuntu devs so probably is better optimised). Note you might be able to use Wine, which is a compatibility layer for windows programs (see here: http://askubuntu.com/q/119041/178596). Also what is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: java version (1.6.0_34)
Open JDK Runtime Environment (Iced Tea 1.13.6) (6b34-1.13.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenDK Zero VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with the other things but for Java... you are trying to install the JDK which is the Java Development Kit, for programmers. You should only need the JRE, which is the Java Runtime Environment; the kit required to run Java applications and the Java virtual machine itself.

Try installing the latest JRE and see if that helps.

Comment: I think I already have. I followed [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get) steps and nothing came back with an error. I don't know how to check for sure though

Comment: Looking your post above you don't seem to be running the latest versions of Ubuntu or the JDK, is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Because I'm really bad at this and don't know how to fix that problem, honestly :)

Comment: I'd recommend starting a fresh install and make sure you download the latest version on Ubuntu to begin with. Look up the latest version of the JRE rather than JDK and install that. Google I can't help with, I run headless systems so I ssh with a command line rather than using a GUI but- don't be scared to ask questions and don't be scared to just break it, wipe it and start over, this is how we learn!